# Check if all fields in the table are empty

Tags: php, mysql

This question may have been asked before, but it's not in the same manner. I'm trying to check if all the fields in a mysql table are empty.

There's an ID fields which is set as Primary key and has an autoindex, so it has a value, but the rest of the columns are empty by default.

This is what I have so far:

```
public function check_empty_table() {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";

    $fields = array();

    if ($stmt = $this->connect->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->execute();
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {


        }
    }

}
```

What else should I add ? It doesn't matter what I grab or how, I just want to throw all the data in that array and then check if the array is empty.

Comment: What database driver are you using? mysqli? PDO?

Comment: by empty do you mean the entire table is empty, or the rows contain empty data.  and by empty data in the rows do you mean null, or the empty string?

Comment: Sorry for not explaining that, if there's no data inside the rows.

Comment: Nothing, nada, empty fields, void.

Comment: `select count(*) from table where col1 = null and col2 = null and ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cool thing about COUNT() is that it doesn't count NULL values.

So, if you do this for each column other than the ID column, and you get zero for each, then it's "blank":

```
SELECT COUNT(COL1), COUNT(COL2) FROM products
```

Comment: Could you show me an example in the manner I'm trying to do it, because now I'm struggling with some other problem, I get duplicate entries when I populate the table.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't write your code today. I happen to be writing my own code.

Comment: No pr :) I'll keep trying then :)

Comment: This solution is fine if you will check always the same table. If you change any field in the table, or you want to apply your function to any other table it's not fine. Think of doing your script more general. You could think in commands such as "SHOW COLUMNS FROM sometable"; http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-list-fields.php (see example 1) to get all the fields in your table and then make your script to count everyone but the ones being PK's

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if the table is empty you can use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table;
```

it should return 0 if there's nothing inside.

Comment: I forgot to mention that there's an ID fields which is set as Primary key and has an autoindex, so it has a value, but the rest of the columns are empty by default.